# Checking npm package (discord.js) version in embed command

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

So, I was wondering if there is any way I can use npm to check the version number for discord.js, like what node has for `(process.version)`, so I can use it in a stats command. It's a small question, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `npm` at all, it would have just read the data from `package.json`. You can parse the `package.json` yourself and get discord.js version from there.

```js
const packageJSON = require("./package.json");

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content == "!stats") {
        const discordJSVersion = packageJSON.dependencies["discord.js"];
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle(`Bot stats - ${client.user.tag}`)
            .addField("Discord.js version", discordJSVersion);
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [embed]
        });
    }

});
```

[image]

<sub>Written for discord.js `^13.0.1` and CommonJS.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried using it in a command handler, but it gives me the error `Error: Cannot find module './package.json'`. Since my commands are in a separate folder. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Adjust the path accordingly to your folder structure. Use `../` to go one directory back.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```js
// From discord.js code
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Discord.js version is ${require("discord.js").version}`);
// From package.json
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Discord.js version is ${require("discord.js/package.json").version}`);

message.channel.send({
  embeds: [embed]
});
```