# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I searched all of Stack Overflow and the internet and found nothing helpful. I tried everything and it tells me the same thing. I'm making a Discord bot and trying to add a role to a user, but it keeps telling me I have an error. I have tried copying exactly what tutorials on YouTube and blogs did, but it tells me the same error. I'm being driven insane; I've tried to debug this error for over a week now. Here's my code:

```
const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
    if(!targetUser) {
        message.reply('ya gotta specify someone to give the role to ya idiot')
        return
    }
//gets the user's username. For example: someone#0001



    args.shift()
//takes user out of the arguments array


    const roleName = args[0]

//finds the name of the role. For example: Mod.


    const { guild } = message
//not sure what this does. I copied it from a tutorial on YouTube. I think it just makes saying guild the same thing as saying message
    const rool = guild.roles.cache.find((role)=>{
        return role.name === roleName
    })
    const role = rool.toString().replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace("@", "").replace("&", "")
//this gets the role id: for example: 912345678901234567



    if(!role) {
    message.reply(`There is no role with the name ${roleName}. btw, you might want to put the person you're adding the role to first, *and then* the role name.`)
//checks if role exists
    }



    const member = targetUser.id
//gets user id. For example: 812345678901234567 
    try{
        member.role.add(role)//THIS IS THE ONE I HAVE TROUBLE WITH. THE ONE LINE! ALL THE OTHERS WORK PERFECTLY FINE. I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT'S WRONG.
    } catch(bad){
    message.channel.send("i have bad bad error: " + bad + ". Please try again later. Much, much later.")
    message.channel.send(`btw, member = ${member} and the role is ${role}`)
    message.channel.send(typeof role)
    message.channel.send(typeof member)

//the role is a string. the member is a string. I checked, and they are right. I've seen other people do the exact same thing as me and it DOESN'T WORK.
    }
```

Feel free to ask for more code if you need it.
Whenever I run the code, because I have a catch, it tells me:

```
i have bad bad error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'). Please try again later. Much, much later.
btw, member = 768522095071985746 and the role is 925077346170585138
string
string
```

Maybe something is wrong with my compiler or runtime environment or all those other weird words programmers use?

Comment: Can we have your Discord.js version?

Comment: @Leau Sure, it's 13.4.0. I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734660/checking-npm-package-discord-js-version-in-embed-command to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access to a `role` property on an id which is not possible since it's not an object, the right way to access to the roles of a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) instance is [`<GuildMember>.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles), `role` one doesn't exists and even less on a [`<User>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();

const roleName = args[0];
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName);

try {
  member.roles.add(role);
} catch(error) {
  message.channel.send('Error');
}
```

Comment: Hey @Leau. Thanks for the reply, but I tried, and because I have a try-catch at the end, it tells me the user and the role from the variables. The bot said it had an error, the same one as before. However, the code at the end told me that the role variable is now <@&912345678901234567> and the user variable is now my discord username, so it pings me. The bot also says that they are both objects, which is what you suggested, right? Anyway, it didn't work. Feel free to make another suggestion or ask for more code. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `member.roles` returns undefined?

Comment: Yes. It is undefined.

Comment: Did you mentionned someone in the message?

Comment: Yes, the command is: !role @me#0000 mod

Comment: Oh yes for sure, replace `message.mentions.users.first()` by `message.mentions.members.first()`, an user doesn't have roles but a member has!

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you. It works now! I've been trying to figure out this error for weeks, but all it took was replacing the users with members! Thanks!